# How to add two text row on same column in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can I add two text row on same column, or any alternative aggregate function which can apply sum() on text columns.

```
id       Name       
1          A        
1          B        
2          C
```

group by id

result like this.

```
id  Names
1   A,B
2   C
```

Comment: Can you explain better please? What are you trying to do? Show us your table definition and some data please

Comment: "2 text row on same column" - do you like a multivalue column? Usually either use meta data like xml, or normalise the multivalue out of the column into another table.

Comment: Concatenating row values in Transact-SQL: http://www.projectdmx.com/tsql/rowconcatenate.aspx

Comment: need group by and then apply sum on text column in groups.

Comment: Nario, show us your tables, some data and desired result if you want to be helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @t table(id int, name varchar(50))

insert @t values(1, 'A')
insert @t values(1, 'B')
insert @t values(2, 'C')


select t.id, 
    ,STUFF(( 
        select ',' + [name] 
        from @t t1 
        where t1.id = t.id 
        for xml path(''), type 
    ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') [Names] 
from @t t 
group by t.id
```

Result:

```
id          Names
----------- --------------
1           A,B
2           C
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. +1

Comment: Seems to be working well, no need to replace special XML characters or things like that. If you need unicode support, change varchar to nvarchar.